# How is it possible to group enums with a super type

Tags: java, enums

I'm currently working at a project where I have two different `Enums` that should be filled in an `Array`. I.e. my Array should be able to hold either one of the Enums. I'm aware that you can't implement inheritance for Enums as you could with classes.

Is there a way on how I can group my two Enums therefore I can put them into the same Array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An [`enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) in Java is implicitly a subclass of the [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html) class. As with most [object-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) languages, Java does not support [multiple inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance). So your enum cannot be a subclass of any other class.

## Share an interface

However… **an enum can implement an interface**. So define an interface to be implemented by both of your two enums.

For example, let's define an interface `Breed`, for various [animal breeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breed).

```java
package work.basil.demo.multienum;

public interface Breed
{
}
```

Define each of your two enums, both implementing that interface.

Some dogs.

```java
package work.basil.demo.multienum;

public enum DogBreed implements Breed
{
    AUSTRALIAN_SHEPHERD , LABRADOR_RETRIEVER , BORDER_COLLIE
}
```

And cats.

```java
package work.basil.demo.multienum;

public enum CatBreed implements Breed
{
    MAINE_COON , MANX , RUSSIAN_BLUE
}
```

Try them out in an example app.

```java
package work.basil.demo.multienum;

import java.util.List;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        List <Breed> breeds =
                List.of(
                        DogBreed.BORDER_COLLIE,
                        CatBreed.RUSSIAN_BLUE,
                        CatBreed.MAINE_COON
                );

        System.out.println( "breeds = " + breeds );
    }
}
```

When run.

```
breeds = [BORDER_COLLIE, RUSSIAN_BLUE, MAINE_COON]
```

Whoops, I now see you asked for an array. Works the same way.

```java
package work.basil.demo.multienum;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Breed[] breeds =
                List.of(
                        DogBreed.BORDER_COLLIE ,
                        CatBreed.RUSSIAN_BLUE ,
                        CatBreed.MAINE_COON
                )
                        .toArray( new Breed[ 0 ] );

        System.out.println( "breeds = " + Arrays.toString( breeds ) );
    }
}
```

In this example we did not define any methods on the interface `Breed`. Be aware that if you do add any methods there, both of the enums must implement those methods. The compiler will notify you if omitted.

## Types and casting

You asked in a comment:

> So, my Interface would work as a "super type" without defining anything to override. Do I understand this correctly?

Yes. Notice the declaration of array in my last example. The variable named `breeds` is an array of objects of type `Breed` (the interface) — not an array of `CatBreed` enum objects, nor an array of `DogBreed` enum objects.

You asked in a comment:

> What happens if an enum implements a method on its own? e.g. `CatBreed` implements `purr()` method. Can I still access this method even though the type is `Breed`?

No. The elements of your array are all `Breed` objects. So when used as a `Breed`, such an object does not “see“ any method specific to `CatBreed`. A `Breed` object sees only the methods defined on the `Breed` interface.

To access your cat's `purr` method, you must cast the [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science)) to a `Breed` object to be a reference to a `CatBreed` object. And you would first test using `instanceof`.

```
Breed breed = breeds.get( 1 )               // Index of 1 means second item, per annoying zero-based counting. We get `CatBreed.RUSSIAN_BLUE` as seen in the example code above.
if( breed instanceOf CatBreed )             // Test if the object referenced by `breed` happens to be also of type `CatBreed` besides being of type `Breed`.
{
    CatBreed catBreed = (CatBreed) breed ;  // Cast to that other type.
    …                                       // Use the `CatBreed` object named `catBreed` to access methods specific to `CatBreed` enum class.
}
```

Java 16 has a new feature, [*JEP 394: Pattern Matching for instanceof*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/394), to make the casting automatic.

```
Breed breed = breeds.get( 1 )               // We get `CatBreed.RUSSIAN_BLUE` from earlier example.
if( breed instanceOf CatBreed catBreed )    // Casting is automatic in Java 16 and later.
{
    …                                       // Use the `CatBreed` object named `catBreed` to access methods specific to `CatBreed` enum class.
}
```

Other related nifty features may be coming in the future because of further work being done with pattern matching, [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395), and [sealed classes](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/409).

---

Caveat: This design (enums sharing an implemented interface) may or may not be an appropriate solution to a particular design problem. I have ignored the issue of appropriateness in my given example, for the sake of demonstrating this approach to a solution.

Comment: So, my Interface would work as a "super type" without defining anything to override. Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: @Beru Yes. Notice the declaration of array in my last example. The variable named `breeds` is an array of objects of type `Breed` (the interface) — *not* an array of `CatBreed` enum objects nor an array of `DogBreed` enum objects.

Comment: What happens if an Enum implements a method on it's own? e.g. `Cat` implements `purr()`. Can I still access this method even though the Type is `Breed`?

Comment: @Beru No, the elements of your array are all `Breed` objects. So when used as a `Breed`, such an object does not "see" any method specific to `CatBreed`. A `Breed` object sees only the methods defined on the `Breed` interface. To access your cat's purr method, you must cast the `Breed` object to a `CatBreed` object. And you would first test using `instanceof`. Java 16 has a new feature, [*JEP 394: Pattern Matching for instanceof*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/394), to make the casting automatic. Other related nifty features may be coming in the future. Search Stack Overflow to learn more.